# Reshaping an untidy data frame

Tags: r, reshape

*Editing in response to comments

I have a dataset that I am trying to prepare for analysis:

```
raw<-data.frame(
  name=c("Place 1", "Place 2", "Place 3", "Place 4"),
  x.1.Jan.12=c(1, NA, 0.5, NA),
  Jan.time=c("0900", NA, "0930", NA),
  x.15.Jan.12=c(NA, 0.7, NA, NA),
  Jan.time=c(NA, "1030", NA, NA),
  x.3.Feb.12=c(0.8, 0.6, 0.4, NA),
  Feb.time=c("0715", "0800", "0830", NA),
  x.8.Feb.12=c(NA, NA, 0.65, 0.33),
  Feb.time=c(NA, NA, "?", "1123")
  )
```

The data should be quite straightforward: a location with a result, a date for the result and the time it was collected.  As you'll see, date has been used to name the variable containing the result.  Each 'time' variable relates to the column before it -  the first 'Jan.time' variable is the time of the results in 'x.1.Jan.12'

I want to restructure the data into four variables - `name`, `date`, `time` and `value`.
I'm pretty sure reshape2 can do it and have got the data melted:

```
mDat<-melt(raw, id=c("name"))
```

Can't work out the next steps - probably to do with the wierd variable names.

The result I'd like is along these lines:

```
outData<-data.frame(
  name=c("Place 1", "Place 2", "Place 3", "Place 4", "Place 1", "Place 2", "Place 3", "Place 4", "Place 1", "Place 2", "Place 3", "Place 4", "Place 1", "Place 2", "Place 3", "Place 4"),
  date=c("1-Jan-12", "1-Jan-12", "1-Jan-12", "1-Jan-12", "15-Jan-12", "15-Jan-12", "15-Jan-12", "15-Jan-12", "3-Feb-12", "3-Feb-12", "3-Feb-12", "3-Feb-12", "8-Feb-12", "8-Feb-12", "8-Feb-12", "8-Feb-12"),
  value=c(1, NA, 0.5, NA, NA, 0.7, NA, NA, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, NA, NA, NA, 0.65, 0.33),
  time=c("0900", NA, "0930", NA, NA, "1030", NA, NA, "0715", "0800", "0830", NA, NA, NA, "?", "1123")
)
```

Comment: I'm not fully sure what output you want (maybe it's just me). I gather you want four columns - `name`, `data`, `time` and `value` - but what values should be in those columns? Can you maybe post how exactly you would like the result to appear?

Comment: Can you explain your current variables a little bit. It seems to be in pairs: A date in January, then "Jan.time", whatever that is. However, why are dates in February also followed by a "Jan.time" column? As suggested by @MadScone, posting an example of the desired output would also be helpful.

Comment: WHAT IS THE CORRECT ANSWER?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I've tried to make the problem a bit clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `melt()` from "reshape2" on different subsets of your `data.frame`. The subsets can be extracted using `grep()`.

```
library(reshape2)
temp <- cbind(
    setNames(melt(raw[c(1, grep("time", names(raw)))], id.vars="name"), 
             c("name", "mon.time", "time")),
    setNames(melt(raw[grep("time", names(raw), invert = TRUE)], id.vars="name"),
             c("name", "date", "result")))
temp[, c("name", "result", "time", "date")]
#       name result time        date
# 1  Place 1   1.00 0900  x.1.Jan.12
# 2  Place 2     NA <NA>  x.1.Jan.12
# 3  Place 3   0.50 0930  x.1.Jan.12
# 4  Place 4     NA <NA>  x.1.Jan.12
# 5  Place 1     NA <NA> x.15.Jan.12
# 6  Place 2   0.70 1030 x.15.Jan.12
# 7  Place 3     NA <NA> x.15.Jan.12
# 8  Place 4     NA <NA> x.15.Jan.12
# 9  Place 1   0.80 0715  x.3.Feb.12
# 10 Place 2   0.60 0800  x.3.Feb.12
# 11 Place 3   0.40 0830  x.3.Feb.12
# 12 Place 4     NA <NA>  x.3.Feb.12
# 13 Place 1     NA <NA>  x.8.Feb.12
# 14 Place 2     NA <NA>  x.8.Feb.12
# 15 Place 3   0.65    ?  x.8.Feb.12
# 16 Place 4   0.33 1123  x.8.Feb.12
```

Answer (score 0):

A new day often helps.  I've managed to work up a non reshape solution, but it uses a dreaded for loop:

```
subList<-list()
for(i in seq(2,8,2)){
  temp<-raw[c(1, i, i+1)]
  temp$date<-rep(names(temp)[2], nrow(temp))
  names(temp)<-c("name", "result", "time", "date")
  subList[[i/2]]<-temp
}

solution1<-do.call("rbind", subList)
```